# Using words of power as a mythic character

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I'm interested in using words of power, but my DM is planning to run a mythic campaign next (Wrath of the Righteous). From what I've read/can find online, it seems that paizo basically treats wordcasting as depreciated. A paizo dev has already said that [they had no plans of supporting wordcasting in the mythic system](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2p5u5?Mythic-words-of-power).

However, my DM is generally pretty flexible; provided I can show that a third party publisher/homebrew rule isn't completely ridiculous. Does anyone have any third party or homebrew rules that they've used in the past to get these two subsystems to play nice together?

Comment: Answers referencing third-party content should [provide context for links](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer); answers providing original (homebrew) content are better when based on experience with the issue at hand rather than pure speculation on what *might* work.

Comment: One thing to consider is that a lot of the mythic spell effects shouldn't be that far off from words; I'm working with a young-world setting that has words as a major form of magic. One thing I'd consider is looking for analogues between WoP and spells and just adopt some of the Mythic effects; Mage Armor and Force Armor, for instance, function similarly (the latter is more powerful, but also more expensive) and the same augmentation (+2 AC and fortification) could probably be applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for any content that blends Words of Power with the Mythic Variant Rules then I'm almost certain you're out of luck. Words of Power has no first party support beyond Ultimate Magic where it was first printed and it's very unlikely that they're going to revisit the system anytime soon. However there have been a couple 3rd Party Publishers that have tried their hand at it.

I don't have it myself but [Words of Power Unleashed by Interjection Games](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9081?Words-of-Power-Unleashed) claims to expand heavily on the Words of Power System and the new book [Deep Magic by Kobold Press](http://paizo.com/products/btpy93ab?Deep-Magic-Print-Edition) supposedly has some Words of Power content.